# /dev/ttyUSB0 doesn't exists

Tags: usb

I have a problem to connected my UPS to my USB port. This is information from my system.

```
warun@Warun-DDPC:~ $uname -a
Linux Warun-DDPC 3.8.0-27-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 00:17:05 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

warun@Warun-DDPC:~ $cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 13.04 \n \l

warun@Warun-DDPC:~ $lsusb |grep Serial
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0665:5161 Cypress Semiconductor USB to Serial
```

**Confirmed that it is this device by reconnect the cable**

`dmesg`:

```
[72169.451629] usb 2-1.6: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[72169.549517] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0665, idProduct=5161
[72169.549522] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[72169.549524] usb 2-1.6: Product: USB to Serial
[72169.549527] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: INNO TECH
[72169.554498] hid-generic 0003:0665:5161.000D: hiddev0,hidraw7: USB HID v1.00 Device [INNO TECH USB to Serial] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
[72685.019094] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[72685.019104] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[72685.019110] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
```

From `/sys/devices/`:

```
warun@Warun-DDPC:~ $ls -ltrad /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6
warun@Warun-DDPC:~ $ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/ -ltrah
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 usb4 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 usb3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 usb2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 usb1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 4-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 3-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 .
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 2-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 2-1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.1:1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.6:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.6 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.2:1.2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.2:1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 19 14:27 1-1.2:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:30 3-3.3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:30 3-3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:30 2-1.6 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:30 2-1.5 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:31 3-3.3:1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.3/3-3.3:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:31 3-3.3:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.3/3-3.3:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:31 3-3:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:31 2-1.6:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 10:31 2-1.5:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0
```

However, it doesn't show any `/dev/ttyUSB*`. I'm not sure what I have missing here.

Comment: There is 500 seconds between these two lines, I'm not sure if they are really related:
[72169.554498] hid-generic 0003:0665:5161.000D: hiddev0,hidraw7: USB HID v1.00 Device [INNO TECH USB to Serial] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0

[72685.019094] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial.
The first part suggests the UPS acts like a input device (maybe a power button?)

Comment: did you look for new device files with other names?

Comment: Jakob I don't think so. @jP_wannN what is your suggestion that I should try?

Answer (score 3):

- Possibly it's created with another name. Check if there is any `/dev` node created by following instruction from [How to allow software access to any USB devices?](https://askubuntu.com/a/632428/26246)
- Same as Jakob said in the comment, it seems that the new device is binded `usbhid` driver. You may check that using:

  ```
  lsusb -t
  ```
- Another way to check all that using `udevadm`

  1. Unplug it
  2. Run udev monitor

     ```
     sudo udevadm monitor -u
     ```
  3. Copy longest path, use it to get all needed info

     ```
     sudo udevadm info -a --path=/sys/<thatpath>
     ```