# How to allow software access to any USB devices?

Tags: usb, permissions, udev

I have a libusb-based program that can't open USB devices on a freshly installed Ubuntu because it lacks permissions.

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/15643/25241) will probably work for me, but it requires manually specifying each and every device - and I have quite a few. So I tried this (in a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/41-cvs-permissions.rules`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", MODE:="0666"
```

I've omitted VID and PID, hoping that it will simply apply the rule to ALL devices. It definitely has some effect, but the effect is rather weird: instead of detecting 5 devices that it can't open, libusb only detects 2 now - both are USB host controllers, not actual devices.

How to achieve what I want?

Comment: IMHO `udev` is frustratingly opaque and poorly documented: I *think* you may need to use attribute `SUBSYSTEMS` (plural) rather than `SUBSYSTEM` (singular). Someone might be able to give a better analysis if you edit your question to include the output of `udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/xxx` where `/dev/xxx` is the actual devpath of your device.

Comment: @steeldriver: I don't see my device having a `/dev/` entry, so I don't know how to invoke `udevadm` on it. All I have is bus, dev. number, VID and PID as shown by `lsusb` (and name).

Comment: @steeldriver: SUBSYSTEM**S** instead of SUBSYSTEM seems to make no difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the easiest solution to unlock access to your hardware:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/bus/usb/`

Answer (score 7):

The way I deal with USB devices is to give a specific group access to all of them.

As root:

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/00-usb-permissions.rules
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Essentially what this does is grant read and write access for any usb device to members of the plugdev group.

Comment: I'll have to find out what a group is, but thanks :)

Comment: Every linux user is a member of at least one, and possibly  more groups.  So if for instance your username was violetg you could do:
sudo usermod -a -G plugdev violetg
 to add yourself to the plugdev group, which would in turn give you access to usb devices (after logging out and back in again).

Answer (score 2):

I agree that making rule match using VID/PID is not a definite solution. But you can much multiple devices in same rule without targeting blindly all USB devices the way you did. Example using `DRIVER` name (`usb-storage`, `usbhid`,..) or `KERNEL` name (`tty*`, `sd*`,..) even using minimal regex (`sd[a-z][0-9]*`, `usb*`).

You should look for similarities in their attributes.

1. Remove all those devices
2. Save the current list of devices in `/dev`

   ```
   ls /dev > /tmp/dev_list0.txt
   ```
3. Plug one of the target devices
4. Save the list of devices in another file

   ```
   ls /dev > /tmp/dev_list.txt
   ```
5. Compare files, `>` added device, `<` removed device

   ```
   $ colordiff /tmp/dev_list0.txt /tmp/dev_list.txt
   85a86,87
   > sdc
   > serial
   89a92,93
   > sg4
   > sg5
   93a98
   > sr1
   194a200,201
   > ttyUSB0
   > ttyUSB1
   ```

   This is a 3G modem.
6. Check the attribute for all interfaces you need, example:

   ```
   udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/ttyUSB0
   ```

Do the same for all devices you want. If you can't figure out how, please upload their `udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=...` output and link them to your question.

Note that, not all USB devices create a node in `/dev`. Some you have look for them in SYSFS tree `/sys`. Then check their attributes using `--path`

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=...
```

Using same steps as above you can check which device nodes created by monitoring `udev` events:

```
udevadm monitor
```