# Execute Script when Android Phone is connected to specified/selected USB Port

Tags: usb, scripts, udev

I´m having some trouble with my `udev` rule. At the moment, I had my udev rule setup to execute a script whenever a Android phone is connected to any USB port on the computer. But I don´t want the script to be executed from every USB port. I just want that the script to be execute in example when the phone is connected to the 4th USB port and nothing should happen when it is connected to 1st, 2nd or 3rd USB port.

How can I achieve that and how can I determine the for example 4th USB Port?

I would highly appreciate your help.

My current udev rule:

```
KERNELS="1-2:1.1", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}!="1d6b", ATTRS{idVendor}!="203a", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ATTRS{idProduct}=="****", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/tmp.sh $attr{serial}"
```

Comment: Check this thread [Mass Storage devices on a selected USB port](http://askubuntu.com/questions/531445/only-use-mass-storage-devices-on-a-selected-usb-port-how).

Comment: @Helio `KERNELS="1-2:1.1", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}!="1d6b", ATTRS{idVendor}!="203a", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ATTRS{idProduct}=="****", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/tmp.sh $attr{serial}"`.
I have no clue how to determine the right USB port.

Comment: You can delete your comment. I put the rule on the question.

Comment: Can you post the`lsusb` output when the phone is plugged on that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, any plugged device get some corresponding nodes in SYSFS `/sys`, some adds other nodes in `/dev`.

- Using sysfs:

  1. Monitor udev events

     ```
     sudo udevadm monitor
     ```
  2. Plug your device and watch for previous command output, example

     ```
     monitor will print the received events for:
     UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
     KERNEL - the kernel uevent

     KERNEL[5797.642807] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4 (usb)
     KERNEL[5797.643604] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0 (usb)
     UDEV  [5797.659463] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4 (usb)
     UDEV  [5798.753894] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0 (usb)
     ```

     So in the format of `bus-port.port:config.interface` see [reference](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6): Bus:2, Port:1 (root hub), Port:4 (external usb port), Config:1 (plugged device), Interface:0

     The full name of USB port is `2-1.4`.
  3. To check its attributes:

     ```
     udevadm info -a /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
     ```

     Or the device (that port is parent node of it)

     ```
     udevadm info -a /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0
     ```
- Using `/dev`:

  Android phone like a modem, it creates a serial port in `/dev`. To know the new plugged device, See [How to allow software access to any USB devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595896/how-to-allow-software-access-to-any-usb-devices/632428#632428)

  ```
  udevadm info -a /dev/ttyACM0
  ```
- Another way, to get port is `dmesg` or :

  ```
  tail -f /var/log/kernel.log
  ```

Then use port number for `KERNELS=="2-1.4"` or `KERNELS=="2-1.4:1.[0-9]*"`

**References:**

- [Linux USB FAQ:What are the sysfs structures for Linux USB?](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#i6)