# Setting an Identifier to USB ports rather than USB devices

Tags: 16.04, usb, systemd, udev

I would like to create dev rules based on USB ports rather than USB devices.

I have two identical cameras where `udevadm info --attribute-walk` on both devices shows no differences. My use case would be akin to having one camera to be the left eye of a robot and the other the right eye. I need the feeds to be processed separately. Since I can't bind with information from `udevadm` as identifiers for my udev rules, I thought it might be possible to map it to a USB port from /sys/bus/usb and always have the cameras plugged in to that port.

I am currently having trouble knowing what information to extract out and the format to add into the camera.rules file.

Suggestions to other methods of solving the problem are more than welcome.

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: You could "close" (see tiny links bellow the post) it as duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/631735/26246 so it bypasses the review queue and minimize needed community effort.